# Need to get the weblogic server username and password at runtime

Tags: java, weblogic

My application is deployed in weblogic server. From within my application I am invoking a secured rest service using the HttpURLConnection. In order to invoke the rest service securely, I need to pass the weblogic username and password. How do I get the weblogic username and password from within my java code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a weblogic "context" and set the username/password in your app if you are a client. Server side, a local context is used:

```
weblogic.jndi.Environment environment = new weblogic.jndi.Environment();
environment.setInitialContextFactory(weblogic.jndi.Environment.DEFAULT_INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
environment.setProviderURL(“t3://myhost:7001”);
environment.setSecurityPrincipal(“weblogic”);
environment.setSecurityCrendentials(“weblogic1”);
InitialContext ctx = environment.getInitialContext();
```

You can get the username/pass from the `boot.properties` in your `<domain>/servers/<server name>/security` folder.

You can also get the username/pass by manipulating the embedded LDAP within Weblogic. Please see:

[Initial Context Factory](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/javadocs/weblogic/jndi/WLInitialContextFactory.html)

[Setting Up JNDI](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13730/toc.htm#i476707)

Comment: I don't need to set the weblogic username and password from within my project. I need to get the already set username/pwd of weblogic within my project at runtime. As I am invoking a secured rest serviced(already deployed on weblogic) from my project, I need to make the call passing the weblogic credentials. So, I need the Java code to get the weblogic username/pwd credentials.

Comment: I don't understand the question... you can get the weblogic username/pwd from the boot.properties file but you will have to decrypt it. Or you can get it from your own properties files... there are many ways to get the weblogic user/pass.